# pandas apply function with arguments

Tags: python, pandas

I have one function that takes three arguments. And here's the heading.

```
def count_ones(num, total_bits, group_size):
```

And I am trying to apply this function to data column. But it is not returning what I expected. Could anyone help me out on this problem? total_bits are 60 and group_size is 12.

```
df['events'] = df['data'].apply(count_ones, args =(60, 12))
```

Comment: why not: `df['events'] = count_ones(df['data'], 60, 12)`? PS I hope your function can deal with vectors...

Comment: "But it is not returning what I expected." What does it return? What do you expect?

Comment: @MaxU my function will take binary integer input and two parameters.

Comment: @DYZ I expect that 'events' column will be populated based on count_ones function applied on 'data' column. Expected value of 'events' column is an array of 5 integers per each row.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Pass the arguments as kwargs to `apply`:

```
df['events'] = df['data'].apply(count_ones, total_bits=60, group_size=12)
```

Answer (score 1):

use lambda:

```
def do_on_col(x, argument1):
  return x+argument1

df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: do_on_col(x, argument1))
```